# Word for "buying more expensive items to go with the expensive item you actually want"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been searching for a word that describes this phenomenon: If a person buys an expensive item, it leads to them buying more expensive items to go with it.

Comment: As in [*conspicuous consumption*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conspicuous+consumption) begets more conspicuous consumption? I suppose [*accessorizing*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/accessorize) might work.

Comment: Greed. And more greed. (I had to add the second greed because you can't comment with only 5 characters. Which is sort of fulfilling the thing you're talking about. Why isn't 5 enough?)

Comment: Overbling ? :-)

Answer (score 2):

This might be a case of [oniomania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oniomania), and such a person might be called an *oniomaniac*. (No, it has nothing to do with onions.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe accessorize?

From Oxford English Dictionary:

> accessorize, v
>
> To provide an outfit or garment with accessories; to make use of accessories.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the impetus for this comes from the seller, who's interested in [upselling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upselling). Leading to...

> [I was **upsold**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%20was%20upsold%22&oq=%22he%20was%20upsold%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.3562040&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22I%20was%20upsold%22&oq=%22I%20was%20upsold%22&gs_l=serp.3...104683.105248.0.105626.3.3.0.0.0.0.78.193.3.3.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.0RZ-okXbykA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=e9fe9caeb27ca466&biw=1253&bih=886) *(About 463,000 results on Google)*